# How can I bend 180 degrees over a duct trunk with height restriction?

Tags: hvac, ducts, product-recommendation

I have to run a flex duct from opposite side of main trunk, as other side of the trunk in the direction flex duct is running is not accessible.

This is in basement, I am using start collar with damper and then attaching 90 degree elbow.

do I add another adjustable elbow on the top of it ?

I wanted to run flex duct from the top of the trunk, but total height of start collar + 90" elbow is 12.5  inch and we need max height of 11 inch ( height of cavity), so thats why I opted for side.

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: If you are using flex ducting why not let the flex make the second 90?

Comment: Aha.  Great. I'll make the 2nd 90 from flex duct then. Thanks Ed Beal.

Comment: You do not _have_ to run flex duct for most of that. I wouldn't. Smooth (rigid) is much preferable. Convert to flex when you really need it. This is a completely common situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule that all your bends need to be plumb and/or level - these things flex for a reason.

Move the start collar to the left (in the picture). Rotate it so that instead of making a  90° straight up, it goes up and to the right. Make your next 90° continue that "up and right" direction until it clears the top of the main trunk, but doesn't hit the ceiling. Wiggle & adjust until you have satisfactory clearance from all surfaces.

---

Thinking more about it (and to be abundantly explicit):

I'd connect the two elbows to make a "straight" 180° turn, then push it up against the trunk line toward the left of the joist bay and "lay it down" toward the right until it cleared the floor above<sup>*</sup>. If you want/need the take off to run down the center of the joist bay, the take off from the trunk can be under a joist above or even in the next bay over - there's no rule about that, either. Once you've got it in a "safe" position, mark the screw holes, cut the appropriate openings and fix it into place.

I'd do this more than adjusting the rotation of the individual elbows, as that may mean that you're not getting them to make the 180° turn you need.

<sup>*</sup>I believe this is the same thing isherwood said in his comment.

Comment: This is the ticket. To put it in simple terms, shift the collar to the side a bit and tilt the two 90s over so their total heights are lower. The wise strategy of "dry fitment" cures all ails.

Answer (score 1):

For sharp turns use 90deg elbows where you can. They are best for preventing flow restrictions under tight turns. To interconnect flex with straights or elbows, use screw clamps.

Purchase the correct diameter for the ducting you have (4, 5, 6in)

They are called clamps, but "clamp" is a very general name (hose clamps, wood clamps, welder clamps...), so searching for "hvac flex duct clamp" will narrow it down quickly.

It will fit around the crimped (squiggly side that slides inside another duct end, as shown in your picture) and uncrimped ducts (straight side that fits over another duct end).

[image]

(Image from amazon.com)

Comment: There's no need for flex duct here, and the more flex you use the more restriction and tendency to collect dust you introduce.

Comment: @isherwood, correct. But OP also asked how to attach it.